# rtmidi's get_ports() returns invalid result with Flask views

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use `python-rtmidi` with `Flask` and trying to display all available MIDI ports on the browser. And noticing two issues while the function gets called from `views.py`.

- `MidiIn().get_ports()` : doesn't recognize a new ports that opened after the flask server started.
- If a port reopened after it was closed (ex: `VMPK Output`) calling the same function `MidiIn().get_ports()`, it wouldn't recognize the new port.
- Calling `MidiIn().get_ports()` from any module works fine. It just whenever it gets called from `views.py`, the above issues occured.
- A similar code works totally fine in [`Quart`](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) framework.

Any idea why it happens with `Flask` and would appreciate if you could shed some light on a workaround.

```py
import time

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from rtmidi import MidiIn

app = Flask(__name__)


def works_fine():
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1']

    time.sleep(5)  # <== Open a MIDI port during this time
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1', 'VMPK Output']]

    time.sleep(5)  # <== Close a MIDI port during this time
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1']


@app.route('/test')
def wont_work():
    # Restart the server
    # and make sure a MIDI device is connected
    # visit : http://127.0.0.1:5000//test
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1', 'VMPK Output']]

    time.sleep(5)  # <== Close a MIDI port during this time
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1']
    # Tbe above code also returns ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1', None] in other tests

    time.sleep(5)  # <== Open a MIDI port during this time
    print(MidiIn().get_ports())  # ==> Outputs: ['Network Session 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1']

    return jsonify({
        'output': MidiIn().get_ports()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question.  Not sure what's difference but running the code with `flask run` causing this issue but `python -m app` works fine.  So I just have to call the `werkzeug` myself (with `Flask` defaults except a couple).

Below results are for after a `MIDI` port closed:

`flask run`

Output:

```
{
"ports":["Network Session 1","IAC Driver Bus 1",null]
}
```

`python -m app`

Output:

```
{
"ports":["Network Session 1","IAC Driver Bus 1"]
}
```

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Blueprints WORKS as well
    # from views import bp
    # app.register_blueprint(bp)

    def get_inports():
        from rtmidi import MidiIn

        inports = MidiIn().get_ports()
        return inports

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return jsonify({
            'ports': get_inports()
        })

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

    run_simple(
        hostname='127.0.0.1',
        port=5000,
        application=create_app(),
        use_reloader=True,
        use_debugger=True,
    )
```